# python Pandas dataframe returns nonetype form a function

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
def create_df():
    data = {'state': ['Ohio','Ohio','Ohio','Nevada','Nevada'],
           'year': [2000,2001,2002,2001,2002],
           'pop': [1.5,1.7,3.6,2.4,2.9]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    return df
create_df()
#print(df) 
#why the  adding print(df) returns nonetype? how can I print this df?
```

**why the  adding print(df) returns nonetype? how can I print this df?**

Comment: You want df = create_df(), not just create_df().

Comment: df is valid within the function. Try `new_df = create_df()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not capturing the return value from the function call `create_df()` . You need to do `df= create_df()` before calling `print(df)` OR altought it is not recomended to make `df` inside the `create_df()` function a global variable, like:  `global df`  But this is generally discouraged.